# Is Microsoft Face API verification (face to face) down? Always says bad request and documentation console shows error

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services

Here is what I've been trying:

```
subscription_key = "***"
assert subscription_key

face_api_url = 'https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/verify'


headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,'Content-Type':'application/json'}
params = {
    "faceId1": "a1cadf80-d780-4b6a-8cef-717548a07e51",
    "faceId2": "05113848-2c22-4116-8a30-5cde938eec61"
}


import requests
from pprint import pprint
response  = requests.post(face_api_url, headers=headers, params=params)
faces = response.json()
pprint(faces)
```

I always get this output

```
{'error': {'code': 'BadArgument', 'message': 'Request body is invalid.'}}
```

Also, I've tried the API testing console and it results in an error always for face to face (haven't tried the others) 
Here's the link to documentation where you can get the links to API testing console.
https://southeastasia.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Verify API we could know that faces should be in the **body** part not in the **params**

```
subscription_key = "xxxx"
assert subscription_key
import json
face_api_url = 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/verify'
headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,'Content-Type':'application/json'}
faces = {
    "faceId1": "xxxxxxxx",
    "faceId2": "xxxxxx"
}

body = json.dumps(faces)
import requests
from pprint import pprint
response  = requests.post(face_api_url, headers=headers,data=body)
result = response.json()
pprint(result)
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

We also could do that easily with python SDK

```
import cognitive_face as CF
KEY = 'xxxxxx'  # Replace with a valid subscription key (keeping the quotes in place).
CF.Key.set(KEY)

BASE_URL = 'https://{location}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0'  # Replace with your regional Base URL
CF.BaseUrl.set(BASE_URL)
result = CF.face.verify("faceId1","faceId2")
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks. it helped. Didn't know that body and params are different.